# cant able to see the menu in 4.x version android phone

Tags: android, android-actionbar, android-menu

I created menu in my activity. i can see the menu in 2.X version but i cant able to see the menu in 4.x version android phone what i did wrong. i tried bellow things
[listview as action overflow in sherlock actionbar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14119237/listview-as-action-overflow-in-sherlock-actionbar/14123377#14123377),
[ActionBarSherlock, ActionBar and Native menu, how to proceed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13648721/actionbarsherlock-actionbar-and-native-menu-how-to-proceed),
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17930664/unable-to-show-the-3-dotted-menu-in-overflow-sherlockactionbar,https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9286822/how-to-force-use-of-overflow-menu-on-devices-with-menu-button/11438245#11438245

```
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    android.view.MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();

    getSherlock().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    return true;
}
@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.close_tab:
         TabHost tabHost = AllFriendList.self.getTabHost();
            int position = tabHost.getCurrentTab();
            Log.d("Position",Integer.toString(position));
            Log.d("Z val in delete()",Integer.toString(z));
            if(position >0)
            {
            tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(position+1);
            z-=1;
            if(z<0)
            z=0;
            }
            else if(position == 0)
            {
            tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(position+1);
            z=0;
            }
            else if(position == z)
            {
            tabHost.getCurrentTabView().setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tabHost.setCurrentTab(z-1);
            Log.d("Z value in final","lol");
            Log.d("Pos",Integer.toString(position));
            Log.d("z pos",Integer.toString(z));

        }
            TabActivity parent = (TabActivity) getParent();
            TabHost tabhost = parent.getTabHost();
            tabhost.setCurrentTab(z+1);
        return true;
        default: 
        return true;
    }   
}
```

Can any one help me 
Thanks

Comment: u have not put a `break` statement noob

Comment: if add break statement i am getting the Unreachable code error

Comment: @Metalhead1247 - You don't need a `break` if you have a `return true`

Comment: @user2873624 remove your return statement and add break instead and check

Comment: thank u every one for your replies. I fixed my problem with this link [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14000784/not-showing-any-sign-of-menu-button-when-there-is-not-any-default-menu-button-in]

Answer (score 0):

Add break in your switch statement.

Comment: I'dont think so...coz he is returning from each case properly, so no break is required...